# Efcore 2.2- where clause runs after selection and returns false results

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have this simple query:

```
Expression<Func<Tips, bool>> lastTipsPredicate = x => x.Status == (int)EnumGringo.LU_Status.active;

IQueryable<Tips> lastQueryBase(DbSet<Tips> t) => t.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).Take(6);
IEnumerable<Tips> latestTips = await base.GetAllByCondition(lastTipsPredicate, lastQueryBase);
```

This is my base repository:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllByCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, Func<DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> baseQuery = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> q = context.Set<TEntity>();

            if (baseQuery != null)
            {
                q = baseQuery(context.Set<TEntity>());
            }

            return await q.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        }
```

This generate this sql query(From profiler):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[CreateDate], [t].[Description], [t].[InsertedByGringo], [t].[IsRecommended], [t].[IsSubscribe], [t].[LanguageType], [t].[SeoId], [t].[Slug], [t].[Status], [t].[Title], [t].[UserID], [t].[ViewCount]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [x].[ID], [x].[CreateDate], [x].[Description], [x].[InsertedByGringo], [x].[IsRecommended], [x].[IsSubscribe], [x].[LanguageType], [x].[SeoId], [x].[Slug], [x].[Status], [x].[Title], [x].[UserID], [x].[ViewCount]
    FROM [Tips] AS [x]
    ORDER BY [x].[CreateDate] DESC
) AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Status] = 1',N'@__p_0 int',@__p_0=6
```

Which returns only 5 records and not 6 as I expected, 1 record is filtered out because it has status!=1.

While this query is the correct one and returns the last 6 records:

```
SELECT top 6 [t].[ID], [t].[CreateDate], [t].[Description], [t].[InsertedByGringo], [t].[IsRecommended], [t].[IsSubscribe], [t].[LanguageType], [t].[SeoId], [t].[Slug], [t].[Status], [t].[Title], [t].[UserID], [t].[ViewCount]
FROM Tips as [t]
WHERE [t].[Status] = 1
ORDER BY [t].CreateDate DESC
```

How can I generate the second query instead of the first one?

Comment: @Thangadurai lol, the first query selects the last 6 records and remove 1 and I left with 5. The second query will return the last 6 records that has status = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Efcore 2.2- where clause runs after selection and returns false results

It's neither EF Core nor LINQ problem, but the way your repository method builds the LINQ query.

If you want to apply filtering (`Where`) first and then optionally the rest, then you should change the `baseQuery` func input type from `DbSet<TEntity>` to `IQueryable<TEntity>`, and the implementation as follows:

```cs
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllByCondition(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> baseQuery = null)
{
    var q = context.Set<TEntity>()
        .Where(predicate); // <-- (1)

    if (baseQuery != null)
        q = baseQuery(q); // <-- (2)

    return await q.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan, once again you have the right answer, can you supply any reference or explain what is the differences between the DbSet and IQueryable?

Comment: The difference from query standpoint is that `DbSet` implements (thus *is a*) `IQueryable`, while the opposite is not true.  Reference: [DbSet<TEntity> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-3.1),